# Default attribute values for my custom view (inherited from LinearLayout)

Tags: android, attributes, custom-controls

I have a custom layout

```
public class PersonView extends LinearLayout{

public PersonView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initUi(context);
}

public PersonView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initUi(context);
}

    private void initUi(Context context){
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.person_view, this, true);
    profilePicture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
    ...
}
```

Layout is defined in xml

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   ...
```

Then I use it in other layout

Case 1

```
// In this case android:layout_margin is specified so it should be used
<my.package.PersonView android:layout_margin="10dp" .../>
```

Case 2

```
// In this case android:layout_margin is NOT specified so I want for my PersonView some default value should be used (say 5pt)
<my.package.PersonView .../>
```

What should I do for my custom layout PersonView to achieve Case 2?

Comment: For PersonView I want to define a set of default attributes.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Only solution I've come up with is to programmatically check in the custom view's constructor to see if the attribute had been set, and if not set it to the default value. This feels wrong, and the default attributes (obviously) don't show up in the graphical view designer.

Comment: Also wondering how to do this - any further news by any chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar problem has been solved at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25982512/3554436

Add `android:layout_margin` to `attrs.xml`

```
<declare-styleable name="PersonView">
    ...
    <attr name="android:layout_margin" />
    ...
</declare-styleable>
```

Access the attribute like other custom attributes:

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PersonView);
float margin = a.getDimension(R.styleable.PersonView_android_layout_margin, 0);
...
boolean hasMargin = a.hasValue(R.styleable.PersonView_android_layout_margin);
```