# Get android:padding attribute programmatically

Tags: android

From a view, how can I get the value of the android:padding attribute programmatically? I am currently using:

```
private static final String ANDROID_NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
private static final String ATTRIBUTE_PADDING = "padding";

public ActivityWrapperView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    int padding = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(ANDROID_NAMESPACE, ATTRIBUTE_PADDING, -1);
}
```

This returns -1, I have also tried using "android:padding" as the attribute name but -1 is still returned.

**EDIT: My requirement: When an android:padding value is specified in the layout XML, the view will use this padding. If a padding is not specified it will use a default padding**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The easiest way was to use android.R.styleable, if it had had been available. The same way it uses for getting custom attributes. R.styleable is a class which contains an int arrays of attributes values.
So you need to create your own int array, which contains int values of atributes you need.

```
public ActivityWrapperView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    //check attributes you need, for example all paddings
    int [] attributes = new int [] {android.R.attr.paddingLeft, android.R.attr.paddingTop, android.R.attr.paddingBottom, android.R.attr.paddingRight}

    //then obtain typed array
    TypedArray arr = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attributes);

    //and get values you need by indexes from your array attributes defined above
    int leftPadding = arr.getDimensionPixelOffset(0, -1);
    int topPadding = arr.getDimensionPixelOffset(1, -1);

    //You can check if attribute exists (in this examle checking paddingRight)
    int paddingRight = arr.hasValue(3) ? arr.getDimensionPixelOffset(3, -1) : myDefaultPaddingRight;


}
```

EDIT as per @Eselfar's comment:
**Don't forget to release the TypedArray:** [arr.recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#recycle%28%29) !

Comment: Isn't getPadding*() available already in constructor?
* in { Left, Right, Top, Bottom, Start, End }

Comment: Don't forget to release the TypedArray:
arr.recycle();

Comment: in android.R.attr, `cardCornerRadius` is not exists. How to solve it?

Answer (score 6):

You can just add the `android:padding` to your custom view's attributes.

```
<declare-styleable name="ActivityWrapperView">
    ...
    <attr name="android:padding" />
    ...
</declare-styleable>
```

And then, you can access the attribute just like your other attributes:

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ActivityWrapperView);
float padding = a.getDimension(R.styleable.ActivityWrapperView_android_padding, 0);
...
boolean hasPadding = a.hasValue(R.styleable.ActivityWrapperView_android_padding);
```

Comment: Is it really ok to add an `android:` prefixed attribute to a custom view?

Comment: @milosmns It can be useful for other attributes like `android:inputType` when you want to be able to set this attribute on your custom view and you also want autocompletion to show Android's built-in values without having to copy / paste every value in your `attrs.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the [`getPadding____()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getPaddingBottom%28%29) functions.

> **Size, padding and margins**
>
> ...
>
> To measure its dimensions, a view takes into account its padding. The
>   padding is expressed in pixels for the left, top, right and bottom
>   parts of the view. Padding can be used to offset the content of the
>   view by a specific amount of pixels. For instance, a left padding of 2
>   will push the view's content by 2 pixels to the right of the left
>   edge. Padding can be set using the setPadding(int, int, int, int) or
>   setPaddingRelative(int, int, int, int) method and *queried by calling
>   getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop(), getPaddingRight(),
>   getPaddingBottom(), getPaddingStart(), getPaddingEnd().*
>
> Even though a view can define a padding, it does not provide any
>   support for margins. However, view groups provide such a support.
>   Refer to ViewGroup and ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams for further
>   information.

Comment: Please see my edit, I need the value of the attribute, not the padding